# Right click to open file in localhost

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

One task that I do all day that is very annoying is working on files and moving them around or adding new files to a folder in my localhost dev server and then I have to go to the browser and navigate to get to the file.

I would assume there has to be a way to be able to add a right click context menu option to "Open File in browser" but to not just open the file in a browser because then it would probably open at the file path to it so my 2 questions

1) Is it possible to add a context menu option using Windows 7 that will alow me to open files in the browser

2) If question 1 is possible, could I then set it to open based off a defined path. Example if the file is located at

```
E:\Server\htdocs\Labs\javascript\socialbuttons\socialable
```

And I access the file in the browser at

```
http://localhost/Labs/javascript/socialbuttons/socialable
```

it would just need to always replace

```
E:\Server\htdocs
```

with...

```
http://localhost/
```

And append the rest on and open in browser.

Any help or ideas appreciated

Comment: AutoHotkey can handle this. I don't have time right now (on my phone, away from computer), but later, I can will write up a script. *(If anyone else is savvy with AutoHotkey, feel free to take on this script in the meantime.)*

Comment: @iglvzx that would be simply amazing and I use AHK I just don't have the skill to write a script to do that, have wrote a couple scripts for uploading screenshots and stuff, I forgot AHK can do almost anything, if you get the time I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: I should clarify. You do not need to add a context menu if you can get the job done with AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can accomplish this by editing the **Registry** and by using **AutoHotkey**. I called my script `OpenAsLocalhost.ahk`, and used similar names for my example.

- Compile the following AutoHotkey script:

```
file = %1%
server = E:\Server\htdocs\
StringReplace, url, file, %server%, http://localhost/
StringReplace, url, url, \, /, All
Run, %url%
ExitApp
```

- Open the **Registry Editor** (`regedit.exe`).
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`
- Create a new Key under `shell\` named `OpenAsLocalhost`.
- Set the `(Default)` value to `Open as localhost`.
- Create a new Key under `OpenAsLocalhost\` called `command`
- Set the `(Default)` value to `"C:\OpenAsLocalhost.exe" "%1"`
- Done!

Comment: Thank you this works flawlessly, I am using Windows 7 x64 and I did not have to hide known extensions, when `F2` is sent, it just copies the first part of the name and doesn't select the `.extension` part so that worked out good.  I would like to incorporate this into a context menu eventually so I think this is a great starting point as it does the functionality part.  I saw some other AHK scripts that added a custom context menu so I'm pretty sure it is possible, if I find the solution for that part I will post it here for you or others to know about.  I appreciate your time thanks again!

Comment: @jasondavis We did it. See my revised answer.

Comment: That is awesome!  I am having a little trouble so far though, were you able to get it working on your system?  If I access the program directly 'OpenAsLocalhost.exe` then I get the error in the attached image http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/full/471430951.png?Expires=1323767957&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIYVGSUJFNRFZBBTA&Signature=WCX3IRAPE8NVfG4LX-TIac08qLevA3bSRxLtmP18hP7NyoBhCU8vjwE8z5h6W-Wx0QL-0Jykpo69dzOx7g8jzoA~XLo4102FTGsqX1ZfIqGLzTypkjX3SLd47Ibu7gp3vBeoYhiHjEHnVrFpNnwANbBiHXFOzC4JgmbzdnTl59M_

Comment: ...continued I am not sure, possibly I am not suppose to ever access the program created directly?  Now after I create the registry entry, I have the menu item.  When I right click on a file and then click the menu item to open in localhost, I get the popup window "Open With" dialog asking me to pick a program to open this file with (even on files that have a default program) If I then pick a program, it will then simply open the file in that program.  If I choose a web browser to open, then it opens it at the file path instead of a web path

Comment: Also here is an image of the regedit entry that I have http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/full/471436492.png?Expires=1323768892&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIYVGSUJFNRFZBBTA&Signature=dPSfWlm83eaA9rfmyongO0gfQnnK6Pez8m20T8RNfMIc743iD7cp5ngL-fpyhQ77-yemS6~UbORS4BISfW~TSTjgbqB~WD0QkSmWg7qO4FzXvT8x6VVLsC1rr3yn~xnymf1oPmBs8b3ooyo65zMXLcUFfOvGN-Y6RmJSrVIRkrA_

Comment: Ah. I forgot to change `C:/` back to your `E:/Server/htdocs/`. Also, you simply need `E:\Server\folder2browser\folder2browser.exe`. You don't need quotes or `%1`. That should fix it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1975/discussion-between-iglvzx-and-jasondavis)